# WinError 3 The system cannot find the path specified: when loading image files

Tags: python, file-not-found

I tried to load image data, but I failed with error:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
```

The code is as below.

```
def load_data():
      datasets = ['seg_train/seg_train', 'seg_test/seg_test']
    size = (150,150)
    output = []
    for dataset in datasets:
        directory = 
            "D:/Hoin/Desktop/호준폴더/Python/Data/intel-image-classification/" + dataset
        images = []
        labels = []
        for folder in os.listdir(directory):
            curr_label = class_names_label[folder]
            for file in os.listdir(directory + "/" + folder):
                img_path = directory + "/" + folder + "/" + file
                curr_img = cv2.imread(img_path)
                curr_img = cv2.resize(curr_img, size)
                images.append(curr_img)
                labels.append(curr_label)
        images, labels = shuffle(images, labels)     ### Shuffle the data !!!
        images = np.array(images, dtype = 'float32') ### Our images
        labels = np.array(labels, dtype = 'int32')   ### From 0 to 
num_classes-1!

        output.append((images, labels))

    return output


(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = load_data()
```

then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-bdc5f874dbf6>", line 1, in <module>
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = load_data()

  File "<ipython-input-58-23e2daec9c02>", line 15, in load_data
    for folder in os.listdir(directory):

  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] 지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다: 
  'D:/Hoin/Desktop/호준폴더/Python/Data/intel-image-classification/seg_train/seg_train'  
(this means ''FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:')
```

I do not know how to solve this problem. I am using `windows` version `anaconda`.
Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: What gives `os.listdir(D:/Hoin/Desktop/호준폴더)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute scripts from different locations by specifying the directory from which to execute from using os.chdir. Doing this may help it find the drive letter D:. This is a common error when developing scripts to run on both Windows and Linux. Just remember to change back to your working directory once done. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/

```
import os

path = r'D:/'

# Check current working directory.
directory = os.getcwd()
print("Current working directory %s" % directory)

# Now change the directory
os.chdir( path )

# Check current working directory.
directory = os.getcwd()

print("Directory changed successfully %s" % directory)
```

Comment: Did not fix the error for me.